# NHibernate - why items attached to a saved object are not saved to the db

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following code:

```
var rootFolder = new KnowledgeFolder { Archived = true, Name = path.First()};
this._folderRepository.Save(rootFolder); // this goes to the db
```

And then later on: (irrelevant code is not here)

```
var child = new KnowledgeFolder { Name = entry, Archived = true };
rootFolder.Children.Add(child);
//////////
this._folderRepository.FlushSession();
```

rootFolder  is correctly saved to the db, but other items that I later add to Children won't save. Why? I know that if root folder was previously downloaded from database this would work. Why NHibernate is not smart enough to check the object graph?

//edit

Mapping is done using fluent api like this:

```
mapping.HasManyBidirectional<KnowledgeFolder, KnowledgeFolder>(g => g.Children, p => p.Parent);
```

Comment: can you show your mapping of the Children ? The children collection has to have cascade ="all" or something like that defined

Answer (score 1):

You arent setting the parent on the child items so nhibernate isn't aware of both sides of the relationship.

```
var child = new KnowledgeFolder { Name = entry, Archived = true };
rootFolder.Children.Add(child);
child.Parent = rootFolder;
```